# Lume omit doctype?

Tags: deno, nunjucks, lume

Is it possible in Lume, using Nunjucks, to refrain from rendering a doctype?

I am using Lume to create HTML snippets, destined for another system.  (I'm not rendering entire HTML pages.)  The doctype gets in the way.

Example input:

```html
<div>Hello world</div>
```

renders thus

```
<!doctype html>
<div>Hello world</div>
```

I'd like it to stop doing that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lume adds the doctype automatically ([see issue](https://github.com/lumeland/lume/issues/223)), but you can remove it with a preprocessor:

```js
site.process([".html"], (page) => {
  page.content = page.content.replace("<!DOCTYPE html>\n", "");
});
```

Comment: Further discussion about this: https://github.com/lumeland/lume/discussions/512